# C++11 Move semantics to prevent transferring the ownership of res from caller

Tags: c++, c++11, std, move

```
template<typename R, typename E>
class Outcome {
            ...
           /**                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
             * casts the underlying result to an r-value so that caller can't take ownership of underlying resources.                                                                                                                                        
             * this is necessary when streams are involved.                                                                                                                                                                                                  
             */                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
            inline R&& GetResultWithOwnership()                                                                                                                                                                                                              
            {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                return std::move(result);                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
            }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                

            inline const E& GetError() const                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
            {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                return error;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
            }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                

            inline bool IsSuccess() const                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
            {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                return this->success;                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
            }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                

        private:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
            R result;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
            E error;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
            bool success;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        };
```

Based on the code above, the getter returned a rvalue reference of private member, isn't std::move make stealing of resource possible? Why the comment says it the caller can't take the ownership?

Comment: It could be a typo.

Comment: The comment doesn't seem to agree with the code.